# Are there any restriction of answering with the bounty system?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I started a bounty on my question for some days.

[How to find the minimum covariant type for best fit between two types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472103/how-to-find-the-minimum-covariant-type-between-two-types)

And now it expires in 3 days. In the past days, it comes even no single answer.

So I'm wondering is that because of it originally is a Q&A style question, that the bounty system prevent people to answer?

---

update:

I experienced two kind of reps wasting with the bounty:

1. Before I started, there are already answers, it still brings new answers. I missed the grace period, but my answer became more voted when I wasn't online, reps wasted.
2. After I started, got many answers, but none solves the question. I left it auto awarding, but all answers have equally voting, reps wasted.

Comment: What makes you think a bounty restricts people from answering? Your self-answer has 14 upvotes, perhaps people find they cannot add anything to that? A bounty's aim is to attract *attention*, answers are **never** guaranteed.

Comment: in your post it seems like bounty is offered  for more traffic instead of another answer  however its legit and there is no problem

Comment: @KenKin: the rep is taken as "payment" for the "advertising" you get from the bounty. It's paid up front, non-refundable (in ordinary circumstances). (Also your bounty message is pretty hard to understand.)

Comment: Also from [the faq](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work): "This feature was designed to motivate answerers, and help questions get the answers they deserve." So no, it certainly doesn't _prevent_ answers.

Comment: "rep being wasted" is a risk one must consider **before starting the bounty**. I lost thousands of points here on Meta on bounties going to the void but totally accept it since I know that's a possible and likely outcome. You can start another bounty (offering more than before) when this one expires but even 500 won't guarantee a good answer.

Comment: I moved the content of my comments to question body.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your answer is *incredibly verbose* and very clearly demonstrates and addresses your problem. It doesn't look like anyone has been able to *better* it, as your bounty asks for.

The bounty **doesn't guarantee a better answer**. It merely guarantees that your question will *most likely* get more attention.

So, by placing the bounty on the question, you've got the attention you wanted, but nobody was able to better your answer.

Comment: Then how can I modify the message of bounty?

Comment: @KenKin You can't, why would that make a difference? People are attracted to the question because of the bounty, chances are they are not concerned with the bounty reason.

Comment: I'm thinking whether I made it too restricted of the implementation, and going to discard some.

Comment: Thank you very much and now there're some new answers.